# Is it faster to make big sql query or to make to small sql query and treat result in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I have a very complex query that is very slow with lots of complex CASE in select.

I was wondering if it would be actually to get the two tables and do logic over them in PHP.

Do you need my full code to tell ? I just added an exemple of a select case to show you the complexity.

```
CASE 
    WHEN (g.date_fin_contrat > :date_quittancement_max) THEN FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,  MAX(g.date_quittancement_echeance), :date_quittancement_max)/12) 
    ELSE FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, MAX(g.date_quittancement_echeance), g.date_fin_contrat)/12)    
    END) nb_echeance_calculee, (
CASE 
    WHEN g.date_fin_contrat > :date_quittancement_max THEN g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance * ((1 - (pow((1+0.02),(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month,  MAX(g.date_quittancement_echeance), :date_quittancement_max)/12))))) / (1-(1+0.02)))  
    ELSE g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance * ((1 - (pow((1+0.02),(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, MAX(g.date_quittancement_echeance), g.date_fin_contrat)/12))))) / (1-(1+0.02)))   
    END) somme_echeance_calculee, (
CASE 
     WHEN g.code_indice LIKE "%\%%" THEN ROUND((g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance*(1+(CAST(REPLACE((SUBSTRING(g.code_indice,1,LOCATE("%", g.code_indice)-1)),",",".") AS DECIMAL(10,4)))/100)),2)
     WHEN g.code_indice LIKE "ICC%" THEN 
          CASE 
              WHEN REPLACE(g.periode_courante_indice_echeance,SUBSTRING(g.periode_courante_indice_echeance,1,4),(CAST(SUBSTRING(g.periode_courante_indice_echeance,1,4) AS SIGNED INTEGER)+1)) IN (SELECT icc_periode FROM indice_icc) THEN ROUND((g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance*(SELECT CAST(REPLACE(icc_multiplicateur,",",".") AS DECIMAL(10,4)) FROM indice_icc WHERE REPLACE(g.periode_courante_indice_echeance,SUBSTRING(g.periode_courante_indice_echeance,1,4),(CAST(SUBSTRING(g.periode_courante_indice_echeance,1,4) AS SIGNED INTEGER)+1)) = icc_periode)),2)
              ELSE ROUND((g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance*(1.02)),2)
          END
     ELSE ROUND((g.montant_ht_actualise_echeance*(1.02)),2)
END
```

Comment: In general, it won't be faster to manipulate your data in PHP versus MySQL.  Databases were designed to handle data in this way, much less so PHP.  So, I recommend leaving this logic in your database.

Comment: If your query is slow, have you tried inspecting the execution plan?

Comment: The only person who's going to be able to answer this question is you, and the only way you'll be able to answer it is by implementing both approaches, profiling them, and picking the most optimal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Generally* slow SQL queries result from large data sets, inefficient joins or sub-queries or lack of indexed fields; not from complex logic in your SELECT or WHERE clause.

You should pull out **complex** logic into PHP where you can lay it out better and comment it. So run the query first and then apply any logic in PHP. Future maintainers of your code-base will thank you.

You should also avoid breaking up the query, if you're only going to end up running one query inside a loop around another query. Instead you should use a UNION or a sub-query or outer join.  Databases are designed for this sort of thing and will be much faster than PHP.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

Often times, for more reasons than just performance, splitting queries up is ideal.

Initially, just try it. If it's faster, the answer is an easy yes.

This also allows you to do things like sharding, service-owned databases and data segregation, ACLs of data, etc.

MySQL is good at a lot of things. Performing complex interactions across multiple sets of data, especially when maintaining overly complex or verbose indexes, you're going to get bad performance. MySQL isn't the best tool for a lot of this; that's why tools like ElasticSearch exist.